# substring in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From the table below

```
 date                description                                  amount
    29/12/13      <13363000054123>JIT BAHADUR LAMICHHANE     CR 10,000.00  TBI 29/12/13 29/12/13
    29/12/13      <13363740800138>MAN BAHADUR .              CR 1,19,595.00  TBI 29/12/13 29/12/13
    29/12/13      <555349302906>CHANDRA PRASAD DAHAL         CR 24,054.30  TBI 29/12/13 29/12/13
    29/12/13      <13362144250203>BISHNU GURUNG DHAN         CR 1,30,562.00  TBI 29/12/13 29/12/13
```

I need the records as below

```
date               description           amount 
29/12/13      <13363000054123>   CR 10,000.00 
29/12/13      <13363740800138>   CR 1,19,595.00
```

I tried substring , but string size cannot be fixed on 'amount' column. What is the best way

Comment: Sorry, on what condition, you filter the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the combination of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING. Assuming amount has format 'xxx.xx'

```
SELECT date, 
       LEFT(description, Charindex ('>', description)), 
       LEFT(amount, Charindex ('.', amount)) 
       + Substring(amount, Charindex ('.', amt)+1, 2) 
FROM   tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

This produce the information you have stipulated.

```
Declare @S varchar(50)
Declare @T varchar(50)
Select @S = '<13363000054123>JIT BAHADUR LAMICHHANE', @T = 'CR 10,000.00  TBI 29/12/13 29/12/13'
Select SUBSTRING(@S, 1, PATINDEX('%>%', @S)), SUBSTRING(@T, 1, PATINDEX('% TBI%', @T))
```

Use this in your query

```
Select date, SUBSTRING(description, 1, PATINDEX('%>%', description)), SUBSTRING(amount, 1, PATINDEX('% TBI%', amount))
```

Comment: TBI is not fixed it may have abc,xyz anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string) to split the amount.
But your schema is quite wrong, you should work on it to avoid theses kind of problems.

Comment: While I agree the schema is questionable at best, what's the value for the OP (or people who find this answer later from a search) in saying that it is quite wrong, but not explaining why or giving an example of how to make it better?

Comment: You're right.I thought about schema normalization : [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
The real amount should be alone in a column ('10 000.00' instead of 'CR 10 000.00' for example)

Answer (score 0):

try this for description column.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    SUBSTRING(description, 0,charindex('>',description)+1)  as description      
from    
    @table
```