# SQL: Obtaining Substring Prior to Dash Character. From 'ABC-123' to just 'ABC'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table CARM with fields (columns) ID and AREA_DESC.

In the AREA_DESC field, I have some values that show as follow:

```
AREA_DESC
--------------
Felisberto-001
Ana
Mark-02
Maria
--------------
```

What I would like to do, is to display these values in this way:

```
AREA_DESC
--------------
Felisberto
Ana
Mark
Maria
--------------
```

As you may notices, I would like to only display the string prior to the dash `-` only. In other words, I would like to drop the dash `-` and numbers after the dash `-`

This is the query I have tried so far:

```
SELECT ID, AREA_DESC ,SUBSTRING(AREA_DESC,0,CHARINDEX('-', AREA_DESC)) as area 
FROM CARM
```

Comment: ... and what's the problem? What you describe, is that the obtained or the desired result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [substring in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878304/substring-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to add a `'-'` for the `charindex()`:

```
SELECT ID, AREA_DESC,
       LEFT(AREA_DESC, CHARINDEX('-', AREA_DESC + '-')) as area
FROM CARM;
```

Notice that this also uses `LEFT()` it saves an argument in the string operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left()` instead with addition of `'-'` at the end of string:

```
select ID, AREA_DESC, left(AREA_DESC, charindex('-', AREA_DESC + '-'))
from CARM;
```